# Pass data from struct initialization to another View Controller

Tags: ios, struct, swift3, initialization, segue

I'm having troubles with passing data from a `struct init`, which is in a `.Swift` file, to an another ViewController. Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

import SwiftSoup

enum HTMLError: Error {
    case badInnerHTML
}

struct GeneralitiesResponse {

    init(_ innerHTML: Any?) throws {
        guard let htmlString = innerHTML as? String else { throw
            HTMLError.badInnerHTML}
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
        let names = try doc.getElementsByClass("name").array()
        let codes = try doc.getElementsByClass("usrname font_size_11 open_sans_condensed_bold").array()
        let schools = try doc.getElementsByClass("scuola").array()



        for i in 0..<names.count {
            let name = try names[i].text()
            let code = try codes[i].text()
            let school = try schools[i].text()

            print(name)
            print(code)
            print(school)
            print("")                                
        }                        
    }                                
}
```

What I need to pass is `name - code - school` inside the `for in loop`.
How can I do? I'm using Xcode with Swift3 and SwiftSoup for parsing.

Comment: Show the code where you call the `GeneralitiesResponse`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to make `for I in 0..<names.count` and use `I` in `names[I]`, `codes[I]` and `schools[I]`, if array count is different your will crash.

Here is what are you trying to do.

```
import Foundation

import SwiftSoup

enum HTMLError: Error {
    case badInnerHTML
}

struct GeneralitiesResponse {
    let names: Array<Element>
    let codes: Array<Element>
    let schools: Array<Element>

    init(_ innerHTML: Any?) throws {
        guard let htmlString = innerHTML as? String else { throw
            HTMLError.badInnerHTML}
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
        names = try doc.getElementsByClass("name").array()
        codes = try doc.getElementsByClass("usrname font_size_11 open_sans_condensed_bold").array()
        schools = try doc.getElementsByClass("scuola").array()
    }
}
```

This function should be in your view controller

```
func parse()throws {
        let gen = try GeneralitiesResponse("html")

        for i in 0..<gen.names.count {
            let name = try gen.names[i].text()
            print(name)
        }

        for i in 0..<gen.codes.count {
            let code = try gen.codes[i].text()
            print(code)
        }

        for i in 0..<gen.schools.count {
            let school = try gen.schools[i].text()
            print(school)
        }
    }
```